# mass update in table storage tables

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is there a way to mass update the [TableStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-overview) entities?

Say, I want to rename all the `Client`s having "York" in the `City` field to "New-York".

Is there some tools to do it directly (without the need to writing code)?

Answer (score 6):

You could try to use **Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer** to achieve it.

First, you have some entities in table storage with a City field in your Storage Explorer.

Then you could **click Export** button to export all your entities to a **.csv file**. 
[image]
Enter **Ctrl + F** and choose Replace item.
Fill the find and replace item with what you want then choose **Replace All**.

[image]

Finally, go back to the Storage Explorer and **click Import** button to choose the .csv file you have edited before.
[image]

Comment: It seems that this is the best way to do it, which is a bit disappointing. I would expect Microsoft to provide a more reliable/reversible alternative than just changing values in an excel, specially for those that would like to change the value of thousands of rows on production for example ...

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the trick with export/import but it's a no go when you have millions of records. I exported all the records and ended up with ~5gb file. Azure Storage Explorer couldn't handle it (my pc i7, 32gb ram).

If someone is also struggling with similar issue, you can do as follow:

1. Export records to csv file
2. Remove the lines that you don't want to modify (if needed). You can use `grep "i_want_this_phrase" myfile > mynewfile` or use `-v` option to find all that doesn't match the given phrase. If file is too large, split it with some command eg. `cat bigFile.csv | parallel --header : --pipe -N999 'cat >file_{#}.csv'`
3. Remove everything except the RowKey column.
4. Prepare `az cli` command similar to `az storage entity merge --connection-string 'XXX' --account-name your_storage -t your_table -e PartitionKey=your_pk MyColumn=false MyColumn@odata.type=Edm.Boolean RowKey=`. Remember about `odata.type`. At first I did an update without this and instead of bools, I switched to strings. Luckily it was easy to fix.
5. Open the file in VSC, select all with `ctrl+a`, then `shift+alt+i` to put a cursor at the end of all lines and then paste previously prepared az cli command. This way you will get a list of az cli updates for each RowKey.
6. Add `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the file, save as `.sh`, modify privileges `chmod +x yourfile` and run.

Of course if you want, you can create some bash script for that and read a file line by line and execute `az` command. I just did it my way as it was much simpler for me, I'm not so experienced in bash, so it would take me a while to dev&test the script.